# Show or Hide form based on radio yes or no selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use Jquery to show more or less of form based on what the user selects. If the user chooses Yes then more form is displayed. I plan on doing this with many different top level questions and then unlocking more questions based on yes or no.

At this link this shows what I have.
http://jcsites.juniata.edu/students/bookhjr10/flashpoint/test2.html

The problem I am experiencing is that a user needs to check yes twice for the question to disappear but it should close when the user checks no.

Code:
JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){


   $('.show_hide').showHide({            
        speed: 1000,  // speed you want the toggle to happen    
        easing: '',  // the animation effect you want. Remove this line if you dont want an effect and if you haven't included jQuery UI
        changeText: 0, // if you dont want the button text to change, set this to 0
        showText: 'Yes',// the button text to show when a div is closed
        hideText: 'No' // the button text to show when a div is open

    }); 


});

</script>
```

HTML form:

```
<form class="form-signin" role="form">
 I am having a Cloud My Office log in issue
<input type="radio" name="myofficeissue" id="0" value="No">No
<input type="radio" name="myofficeissue" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv"  id="1" value="Yes">Yes
    <div id="slidingDiv">
        I am having a username and password issue.
      <input type="radio" name="passwordissue" id="passwordissue-0" value="No">No
      <input type="radio" name="passwordissue" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv_2" id="passwordissue-1" value="Yes">Yes
    </div>   
 <a href="#" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv_2"></a><br />
    <div id="slidingDiv_2">
    I need to reset my password
      <input type="radio" name="password" id="password-0" value="No" checked="checked" required> No
      <input type="radio" name="password" id="password-1" value="Yes" required>   Yes
      </br>
        My username needs updated.
      <input type="radio" name="username" id="username-0" value="No" checked="checked" required> No
      <input type="radio" name="username" id="username-1" value="Yes" required> Yes</br>
My account is locked out
<input type="radio" name="locked" id="locked-0" value="No" checked="checked" required> No
      <input type="radio" name="locked" id="locked-1" value="Yes" required> Yes</br>
I am experiencing other problems
      <input type="radio" name="other" id="other-0" value="No" checked="checked" required>No
      <input type="radio" name="other" id="other-1" value="Yes" required>Yes</br>
    </div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
<style>

body{
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;}

#slidingDiv, #slidingDiv_2{
    display:none;
}


</style>
```

My questions are. Is this the best way to do something like this?
Is there a way to make it so that the No option closes the div?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant code..

Comment: You are toggling the divs on click, which is what causing the *yes* option to show/hide the divs with more questions. Post the code.

Comment: In addition to posting any relevant code in your question, it may be helpful to create (and link to) a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mU5H5/2/ The Jfiddle isn't working but it works on the regular link.

Comment: The Javascript file included by your live test2.html is not the same as what you have provided above and in the fiddle. More specifically, there is an additional file included by test2.html that you are not showing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see your project getting quite complex so I don't think having all the logic in the javascript would be the right way to go about this. So I've created a sort of logic controller in the javascript and separated out the logic requirements into the html with some data attributes.

[Here is the code in action.](http://jsbin.com/rehomuhe/1) This solution is now very flexible and easy to maintain. All you need to do is wrap the parts that need to appear and disappear in a `div` and give them an attribute called `"data-view-conditions"`. This attribute can contain mutiple conditions that need to be met in order for it to display.

The conditions are comma separated and contain an input name and a required value. Which are in turn separated by a colon. This supports both radio and checkbox inputs. You can also supply just a name without a value and the condition will "match" if that input is at least checked or selected without caring about the value. Below are some example conditions.

```
data-view-conditions="name"

data-view-conditions="name:1"

data-view-conditions="name:1,name2:3,name3:test"

data-view-conditions="name4:123,name5"
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($){

  // Prevents errors in old IE.
  if(!window.console || !window.console.log) window.console = {log: function(){}};

  // Enable debugging for complex logic.
  var debug = true;

  function checkConditions(inputs, views){
    views.each(function(){
      var view = $(this);
      var conditions = view.attr('data-view-conditions').split(',');
      var display = true;

      // Loop over all required conditions to be met.
      for(var i = 0; i < conditions.length; i++){
        var name = conditions[i].split(':')[0];
        var value = conditions[i].split(':')[1];
        var input = inputs.filter('[name="' + name + '"]:checked');

        if(debug) console.log('\nRecalculating view conditions.');

        if(!input.length){
          display = false;
          if(debug) console.log('View not show as no :checked input with the name "' + name + '" was found.');
        }else{
          if(value != undefined && input.val() != value){
            display = false;
            if(debug) console.log('View not show as no :checked input with the name "' + name + '" has the value of "' + input.val() + '". Value needed was: "' + value + '".');
          }
        }
      }

      if(display){
        view.css({display: 'block'});
      }else{
        view.css({display: 'none'});
      }

    });
  }

  $('form').each(function(){
    var form = $(this);
    var inputs = form.find('input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]');
    var views = form.find('[data-view-conditions]');

    // Recalculate which views to be shown each time the inputs change.
    inputs.on('change', function(e){
      checkConditions(inputs, views);
    });

    // Check conditions to set up required view state on page load.
    checkConditions(inputs, views);
  });

});
```

HTML:

```
<form>

  <label for="i1">Input 1</label>
  <input id="i1" type="radio" name="name1" value="1">

  <label for="i2">Input 2</label>
  <input id="i2" type="radio" name="name1" value="2">

  <div data-view-conditions="name1:2">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <label for="i3">Click me</label>
    <input id="i3" type="checkbox" name="name2">

    <div data-view-conditions="name2">
      <p>It works!</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to understand your code and actually change it and use. +1

Comment: @Pureblood You're very welcome, I'm glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve your requirement using jquery change event.

http://jsfiddle.net/mail2zam/vQ4Up/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input:radio").change(function(){
    console.log(this);
    if(this.value == 'Yes' && this.name == 'myofficeissue'){
        $('#slidingDiv').slideDown();
    }else if(this.value == 'No' && this.name == 'myofficeissue'){
        $('#slidingDiv').slideUp();
        $('#slidingDiv_2').slideUp();
    }else if(this.value == 'Yes' && this.name == 'passwordissue'){
        $('#slidingDiv_2').slideDown();
    }else if(this.value == 'No' && this.name == 'passwordissue'){
        $('#slidingDiv_2').slideUp();
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Selecting `yes` for the first question should always show the next question, and `no` should always hide the next question. Currently `yes` is toggling between shown and hidden.

Same with selecting `yes` or `no` for the second question and showing the subsequent questions.

As far as good user interface goes, using radio inputs the way you currently are doesn't feel right. If you do use radio buttons, wrap both the radio `<input>` and the text belonging to it in a `<label>` tag so that clicking the text selects the radio. This makes a much bigger target for your user to click on. The same applies for checkboxes.

Radio inputs make more sense when you have to pick one option out of three or more. Two works, but with only two possibilities there are usually more suitable input types. For your last set of questions, checkboxes would make more sense than a series of radios.